# On adding data, it show "Too few parameters. Expected 1"

Tags: c#

The problem says:

> Too few parameters. Expected 1.

Here's my database table:

> CustomerOrder [CustomerOrder(OrderId, ProdName, ProdPrice, OrderQty, CatName, OrderDate]

Code:

```
con.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CustomerOrder(OrderId, ProdName, ProdPrice, OrderQty, CatName, OrderDate)values('" + txtOrderCode.Text + "','" + txtProdName.Text + "', '" + txtProdPrice.Text + "', '" + txtOrderQty.Text + "', '" + txtCatName.Text + "', '" + txtOrderDate.Text + "')";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage1;
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
con.Close();

int ordercode, orderqty;
double price;
string prodname, catname;
ordercode = Convert.ToInt32(txtOrderCode.Text);
orderqty = Convert.ToInt32(txtOrderQty.Text);
price = Convert.ToDouble(txtProdPrice.Text);
prodname = Convert.ToString(txtProdName.Text);
```

Comment: There's a missing space before `values`. And the code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: Drop everything you are doing and go read about SQL Injection and parameterized queries.

Comment: Which line of code gives that error?
  Also, calling `Convert.ToString(txtProdName.Text)` makes no sense.  `txtProdName.Text` is already a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you use parametrised queries instead as it will prevent you from Sql Injection Attacks.  Here is a small example of how it could work with your code

```
String SqlCommand = "insert into CUSTOMERORDER values (@OrderId, @ProdName,@ProdPrice,@OrderQty, @CatName,@OrderDate)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlCommand , //ConnectionString);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
conn.Open();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderId", txtOrderCode.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdName", txtProdName.Text );
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProdPrice", txtProdPrice.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderQty", txtOrderQty.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CatName", txtCatName.Text.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderDate", txtOrderDate.Text);


cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Read up on Sql Injection attacks.  Doing it this way is much easier, cleaner and most importantly, safer.  Also when looking at your code you are setting the text box values after you have ran the Sql command